# How to read csv coordinates and plot them with javascript?

Tags: javascript, csv, coordinates, openstreetmap

I've a problem reading a csv file with javascript. It's a multiline csv with columns about coordinates(latitude and longitude in a list together in this way: [latitude, longitude] and location name. (Columns separated by ;) How can I read the csv file and add a marker for every location in a map using coordinates, in javascript?
I can't open my file (2 columns and 189 rows), and I can't add marker.
I've found code here and in other sites, but I still not understand how to read csv and use the information correctly.

```js
bike = d3.csv('bike_coordinate.csv')
var customIcon = L.icon({
  iconUrl: '',
  iconSize: [38, 40], // size of the icon
  iconAnchor: [10, 40], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
  popupAnchor: [5, -40] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
});
var tmp_marker = L.marker(bike.coordinates(), {
  icon: customIcon
});
marker_array.push(tmp_marker);
tmp_marker.addTo(mymap).bindPopup(bike.Indirizzo());
```

Comment: You've listed a few things there — let's try to narrow things down a bit. Are you having trouble (1) reading the file or (2) adding markers to the map? Can you update your question to limit it to only those things you've already attempted but are stumped at?

Comment: Hi Alice, welcome to SO. Could you elaborate your question a bit. What map are you using? Or are you looking for advice on what to use? I would suggest checking out the following example: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple

Comment: I've tried several code found here and in another site.I can't open my csv and can't add marker. I'm using leaflet with openstreetmap.

Comment: To format code, indent 4 or more spaces. I removed the confusing else

Answer (score 1):

Try csvtojson : https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvtojson

csvtojson module is a comprehensive nodejs csv parser to convert csv to json or column arrays. It can be used as node.js library / command line tool / or in browser.

It will take your csv file and output a json array that you can load into your map.

Comment: Thank you! It's very usefull. I transformed my csv in a json file, if I want to read it in another javascript and use the information how does it work? I tried $.getJSON but the length is 189, it's silly to write 189 alert: alert(mydata[0].coordinate), alert(mydata[0].Indirizzo), Is there a better way to write it?